# 403 Forbidden error updating while in Anchorage, Alaska

Tags: ubuntu, software-updates

This seems odd but it only happens when it's in Anchorage. I'm trying to update my Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and issue "sudo apt update" but this is what I'm getting:

```
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-security/main/binary-amd64/Packages 403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.38 80] 
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic-updates/main/binary-amd64/Packages 403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.38 80] 
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/bionic/universe/binary-i386/Packages 403  Forbidden [IP: 91.189.91.38 80] 
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.`
```

This is a fresh-install and have tried many times with different VMs in Anchorage but with the same error.

I also tried a different mirror site in Canada but to no avail.

What's puzzling is I have done the same thing to another site we have in Colorado and it went fine. Any ideas what is going on?

Here's my /etc/apt/sources.list

```
## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic multiverse
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ bionic-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
# deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security multiverse
```

Answer (score 1):

This command fixed it:

```
sed -i s/http/ftp/ /etc/apt/sources.list && apt-get update
```